# Parse subQuery filter swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am running a PFQuery on the main _User table (ACL is read-only if the user isn't the PFUser.currentUser).

I am logging a count for profile views.

Since the PFUSer table cannot be incremented by anyone other than the currentUser, I have to store the count in a separate table. Call this table "ViewCount," with pointer column "userId" that points back to the PFUser table.

How can I filter a query on the main PFUser table for users with a given count from the ViewCount table?????

```
 let query = PFUser.query()!

 //perform filters here

 query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a subquery.

```
let query = PFUser.query()!

let subQuery = PFQuery(className: "viewCount")
subQuery.whereKey("count", greaterThan: yourCount)
query.whereKey("userCount", matchesQUery: subQuery)

...
//rest of query info
```

Comment: pbush, this worked for a filter, but if i want to retrieve the fields like a SQL join, how would I do that?  If the answer is to create a pointer in my User table, how do i create a pointer to viewCount with code?

Comment: do you know how to put the pointer in the user table with code?  i have only been able to put pointers into custom tables, not into the _User table.         my goal is to do the following     SELECT  _User.field1,  _User.field2,  (SELECT viewCount.field1 from viewCount where viewCount.field1 = _User.field1)  From...  Where...